# Move the text down in 'a' snippet in sidebar when it hit the right border

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my style.css. I am very noob in programming. Im trying to give text beside the image I attach in sidebar. However, the text seems to flow pass the border

This is the html text:
[See this first to find where is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrapP.png)

and this is what happened after I run the html :
[This is what is displayed in the output, the text is flowing outside the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmKG7.png)

This is the full code I run in both css and html file

```css
.contentone {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.contenttwo {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#customnavbar {
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}


/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar:hover {
  min-width: 265px;
  max-width: 265px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidebar.active {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active:hover {
  min-width: 95px;
  max-width: 95px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  margin-left: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#content.active {
  margin-left: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #content.active {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -80px !important;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
  #sidebar .CTAs {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a span {
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
{% load static %}
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,8,edge" />


  <title>SecondBrain</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static " css/mainstyle.css " %}" title="" type="" />



  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>Category</h3>
        <strong>SB</strong>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <br/> Beranda
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
            <br/> Tentang
            <br/> Kami
          </a>
          <a href="#dasarSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-copy"></i> Pendidikan Dasar
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="dasarSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">SD</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">SMP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">SMA</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">UMUM</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#lanjutanSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-image"></i> Pendidikan Tinggi
          </a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="lanjutanSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Teknik Mesin</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Teknik Metalurgi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Statistika</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Arsitektur</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
            <br/> FAQ
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
            <br/> Contact
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
        <li>
          <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="customnavbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <strong>
                <h2 class="mx-auto">
                <img src="{% static "images/brain_sample.png" %}" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                SecondBrain.id
                </h2>
              </strong>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav class="">
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-info">
              <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
              <span>Category</span>
            </button>
        <p></p>
      </nav>


      <div class="jumbotron">
        {% block title %} {% endblock title %}
      </div>


      {% block content1 %} {% endblock %} {% block content2 %} {% endblock %}




      <p>, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>sse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>int occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, t occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>








  </div>

  <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Popper.JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        $('#content').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However I cant pinpoint where is the problem and what should I do. I have tried using flex-wrap, text-wrap, display flex, however it still didn't work like I hope.
What I realize is I can't affect the text within 'a' snippet. And sorry if my code is a mess and hard to read.

So please help me, or you could just direct me to relevant link. Thank you

Comment: Please share the whole code so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: @YalcinKilic Done. I attach the whole code. Hope it help clear what is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add white-space: normal; on your anchor tag.

```css
.dropdown-toggle{
white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lanjutanSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-image fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="image" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M464 448H48c-26.51 0-48-21.49-48-48V112c0-26.51 21.49-48 48-48h416c26.51 0 48 21.49 48 48v288c0 26.51-21.49 48-48 48zM112 120c-30.928 0-56 25.072-56 56s25.072 56 56 56 56-25.072 56-56-25.072-56-56-56zM64 384h384V272l-87.515-87.515c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.971 0L208 320l-55.515-55.515c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.971 0L64 336v48z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-image"></i> --> Pendidikan Tinggi
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the class `.dropdown-toggle` has `white-space: nowrap` thats why your links overflowing. The other thing is your Sidebar has `max-width` property.
So there are two simple solutions for this. Either you have to do it like @Amarender answered or you allow the sidebar to grow appending to the content

Comment: I wish I could. But my reputation is not enough yet to give a change in thumbs up display XD